# DDD - child entity encapsulation

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregate, encapsulation

Given the following example aggregate:

```
public class Order
{
    private readonly IList<OrderLine> _orderLines;
    public IEnumerable<OrderLine> Lines { get { return _orderLines; } }

    public Order()
    {
       _orderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
    }

    public void AddOrderLine(string sku, int qty)
    {
        _orderLines.Add(new OrderLine(sku, qty));
    }

    public void CancelOrderLine(string sku)
    {
         OrderLine line = _orderLines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Sku == sku);
         if (line == null)
            return;

         line.Cancel();
    }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string Sku { get; private set; }
    public int Qty { get; private set; }

    public OrderLine(string sku, int qty)
    {
       Sku = sku;
       Qty = qty;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        // do some cancellation stuff
    }
}
```

What is to prevent someone from going around the aggregate root and modifying the OrderLine directly?  For example:

```
foreach(OrderLine line in currentOrder.Lines)
{
   line.Cancel();
}
```

Is there anyway to have a truly encapsulated aggregate root?  Would the only solution be to create a set of parallel order lines value objects that get exposed instead?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you start with making the Cancel method internal so it is only visible inside your Order assembly?
Off course other classes in this assembly can then still access the cancel method.

Maybe another way is to expose the collection of OrderLines as a collection of IOrderLine interfaces and hide the Cancel method that way.

Comment: Yes, I considered making the methods internal to lessen the exposure and will probably do that. Also considered the interface route, but someone could cast the result back to an OrderLine object and call the cancel method directly.  I know that's bordering on paranoia, but I guess I'm wondering if there is a "correct" way to do this that provides true encapsulation or will I have to settle for a compromise here?  If I don't get any better answers I will accept yours.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expose Lines? Expose some snapshot (DTO) containing information about OrderLines that you need outside but not OrderLines themselves. It's known solution. And with CQRS you may not need to expose it at all.

Comment: From what I've read DTO's have no place in the domain itself.  It would also be very tedious to create snapshot objects for all my child entities.  On a side note, I discovered that returning the list like this: public IEnumerable<OrderLine> Lines { get { return _orderLines.AsEnumerable(); } }  solves the issue.  Modifying the returned lines will not affect the ones stored in the aggregate.  Seems a copy is made instead.